# What to use instead of threads with quart

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I want to make a discord bot dashboard with replit and I want to use quart, there is my keep_alive function:

```py
def run():
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

def keep_alive():
  server = Thread(target=run)
  server.start()
```

There is just one little problem, I don't know what to use instead of thread because Quart is an **asynchronous** library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`hypercorn.asyncio.serve`](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/how_to_guides/api_usage.html#api-usage), you can turn an ASGI server (i.e., Quart here) to an [`asnycio.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) object, which allows you to push the `Future` to event loop (by `asyncio.create_task` or something else) and run it at background.

Answer (score 1):

Quart `run` takes the following arguments. if you want to reload on file changes then it does the job by default.

```
def run(
    self,
    host: Optional[str] = None,
    port: Optional[int] = None,
    debug: Optional[bool] = None,
    use_reloader: bool = True,
    loop: Optional[asyncio.AbstractEventLoop] = None,
    ca_certs: Optional[str] = None,
    certfile: Optional[str] = None,
    keyfile: Optional[str] = None,
    **kwargs: Any,
) -> None:
```

Answer (score 0):

`shutdown_trigger` must be set if you run the hypercorn in a non-main thread. Or you'll get exception while hypercorn initializing its default shutdown_trigger: `ValueError: signal only works in main thread`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html

```py
import asyncio
import signal
import threading

import hypercorn
from hypercorn.asyncio import serve as hypercorn_asyncio_serve
from quart import Quart

# please notice that it's not the threading.Event!
event = asyncio.Event()

app = Quart(__name__)
app.debug = False


async def set_async_event():
    event.set()
    loop.call_soon(loop.stop)

def signal_handler(_, __):
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(set_async_event(), loop)

    # waiting for event loop closing
    while True:
        if not loop.is_running():
            logger.bind(o=True).info('Async http server closed.')
            break
        time.sleep(0.1)

    # then exit this main thread, with daemon async thread
    exit(1)


# the default hypercorn shutdown trigger binds these three signals
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, signal_handler)


# Then start this module in a non-main thread
def start_background_loop(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> None:
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
t = threading.Thread(target=start_background_loop, args=(loop,), daemon=True)
t.start()

# not event.wait()! will prevent all API methods performing.
coroutine = hypercorn_asyncio_serve(app, hypercorn.config.Config(), shutdown_trigger=event.wait)
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coroutine, loop)
```

[full source code of my project (have changed, please follow newest answer content, link remained for further referring)](https://github.com/boholder/modron/blob/0d284b24ec680914eed906c61baf916c555dc56e/monodrone/src/monodrone/__main__.py#L12)